# How can a SDK track in-app purchases automatically?

Tags: ios, sdk, in-app-purchase, analytics, storekit

To track my in-app revenues in Google Analytics, I have to call a specific tracking function with name, revenue etc.
Apsalar doesn't need that. It can automatically track purchases and revenues without additional code. How?

Now I have to solve this because I am required to develop a SDK that should track a users lifetime value. This SDK will be integrated into some apps, and I can't trust the developer party to report every transaction one by one. The SDK should be able to find it on its own.

Two things come to my mind, although I have no idea if they are correct or even possible.

1. Register for some global notification that fires when a purchase completes.
2. Observe the status of the default transaction queue and act accordingly.

Does anyone know how to work this out?

Thanks in advance.